# Why is autoboxing/unboxing failing here?

Tags: java, autoboxing

In the program below, the result is that `0.0` is considered less than `Double.MIN_VALUE`. Why?

We have a solution (work with `Doubles` only and use `compareTo`) and I want to understand why unboxing is failing here.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double max = 99999.9999;
    double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    Double test = 0.0;

    System.out.println(max > test); // expect true; is true
    System.out.println(test > min); // expect true; is false
  }
}
```

Comment: Going to add a link to a previous SO question that has an excellent answer from @aioobe. IMO Sun should have named this constant something more intuitive but that ship has sailed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/minimum-values-and-double-min-value-in-java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) :

> MIN_VALUE
>
> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

In other words, it is bigger than 0.

Answer (score 5):

You should read the [Double.MIN_VALUE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) specification.
It's a minimum possible but positive Double value which means it's larger than 0.0.

```
A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2-1074.
It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal 0x0.0000000000001P-1022
and also equal to Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).
```

Answer (score 2):

`Double.MIN_VALUE = 4.9E-324` which is still a positive number. I think you are looking for `min = - Double.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

According to me autoboxing has no problems. 
Perhaps you simply need to use something like Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY or Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY that should work well with the < and > operators. For example note that

```
-Double.MAX_VALUE > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
```

is true!