# Poisson Distrubtion using Normal Approximation in Java

Tags: java, statistics, probability, normal-distribution, poisson

If you are unsure of what "Poisson Distrubtion using Normal Approximation" means, follow this link and check the texts inside the yellow box. 
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/180

Here, is the simple snapshot of the math from the link.

P(Y≥9) = P(Y>8.5) = P(Z>(8.5−6.5)/√6.5) = P(Z>0.78)= 0.218

So to get the value in .218, we use Simpson's integration rule which 
integrates the **function**(Implemented in method named "f" from code below) from "negative
infinity" to the value that equals to this >> "((8.5−6.5)/√6.5))"

**R** successfully gives the correct output. But in **Java** when i implemented the code
below copied from "http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/93integration/SimpsonsRule.java.html"
I get "**0.28360853976343986**" which should have been "**.218**" Is it any how because of the negative infinity value I am using, which is "**Double.MIN_VALUE**"

This is the code in Java. **See at the very end for my INPUTS in the main method**.

```
       * Standard normal distribution density function.
       * Replace with any sufficiently smooth function.
       **********************************************************************/
       public static double f(double x) {
          return Math.exp(- x * x / 2) / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
       }

      /**********************************************************************
       * Integrate f from a to b using Simpson's rule.
       * Increase N for more precision.
       **********************************************************************/
       public static double integrate(double a, double b) {
          int N = 10000;                    // precision parameter
          double h = (b - a) / (N - 1);     // step size

          // 1/3 terms
          double sum = 1.0 / 3.0 * (f(a) + f(b));

          // 4/3 terms
          for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i += 2) {
             double x = a + h * i;
             sum += 4.0 / 3.0 * f(x);
          }

          // 2/3 terms
          for (int i = 2; i < N - 1; i += 2) {
             double x = a + h * i;
             sum += 2.0 / 3.0 * f(x);
          }

          return sum * h;
       }



       // sample client program
       public static void main(String[] args) { 
           double z = (8.5-6.5)/Math.sqrt(6.5);
           double a = Double.MIN_VALUE;
           double b =  z;
           System.out.println(integrate(a, b));
      }
```

Anybody has any ideas? I tried using **Apache math's "PoissonDistribution" class's method "normalApproximateProbability(int x)"**. But the problem is this method takes an "int".

Anyone has any better ideas on how do I get the correct output or any other code. I have used another library for simpson too but I get the same output.

I need this to be done in **Java.**

Comment: Take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/minimum-values-and-double-min-value-in-java). `Double.MIN_VALUE` might not be what you think...

Comment: Tried all of them. "-Double.MIN_VALUE", "-Double.MAX_VALUE", "Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY", no hope.

Comment: Run out of time today. I think you should use `-Double.MAX_VALUE`. I had time to debug your code a bit and I think you might be facing the "typical" floating point rounding errors (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). Maybe could try rewriting your function so that instead of going from `a` to `b` with step `h`, you go from `b` to `a`. I think this way you could avoid the errors, but please take into account it is a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for your time. -Double.MAX_VALUE gives me a number greater than 1. You mean b to a as in "h = (a - b) / (N - 1);" . If I do it or not, for the "Double.MAX_VALUE" i am getting value greater than 1. Which it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the code by writing another method that implements Simpson's 3/8 rule instead of your integrate function. It gave the same result as the one you obtained at first time. So i think the difference arises most probably from rounding errors.

Comment: You know instead of "Double.MIN_VALUE", I used "-150"..It gave me the correct output. So weird. I started playing with negative number as great as -10000 and then lowering it down. . But yeah "-150" is not the answer to this question. @lrnzcig