# Returning the largest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in Java and I am trying to figure out why my method is not returning the largest value in the input array. My idea is the when the method is called, the for loops will search through every value of the array. Then it begins setting the first value as the largest value and any value that is greater than that value then becomes the largest value thereafter.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
public double displayLargest (double[][] l) {
    for (int x=0; x < l.length-1; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < l[x].length; y++) {
            double w = l[0][0];
            if (w < l[x][y]) {
                x++;
                y++;
                w = l[x][y];
                maxValue = w;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The largest value in the array is: " + maxValue);
    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: Gawd, I hate single character variables, makes the code so hard to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method will return the largest value in the 2D input array of `double` and it will return `null` if no values are present.

```
public Double displayLargest(double[][] l){
    Double maxValue = null;

    for (int x=0; x < l.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < l[x].length; y++) {

            if (maxValue == null || maxValue < l[x][y]) {
                maxValue = l[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The largest value in the array is: " + maxValue);

    return maxValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    double maxVal = -Double.MAX_VALUE;  // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/why-is-double-min-value-in-not-negative
    for(int x =0; x<l.length; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<l[x].length; y++){

            double w = l[x][y];
            maxVal = Math.max (maxVal, w);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The largest value in the array is: " +maxVal);
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(double,%20double)

Answer (score 0):

```
double max = l[0][0];
//two loops here
if(max < l[x][y])//inside two loops
{
   max = l[x][y]
}
```

You are always assigning the first value of the array to w, you should declare it before any loops. Otherwise, you are always comparing the value with l[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

I had given simple method to do so.

```
int[][] array2 = 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
    {16,17,18,19}};
      int result = Arrays.stream(array2)
    .flatMapToInt(h2 -> Arrays.stream(h2))
    .min()
    .getAsInt();
      System.out.println(result);
```

this is for max

```
int[][] array2 = 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
    {16,17,18,19}};
      int result = Arrays.stream(array2)
    .flatMapToInt(h2 -> Arrays.stream(h2))
    .max()
    .getAsInt();
      System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would **strongly** *recommend* you start with meaningful variable names. Next, I would urge you to prefer the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) over the traditional `for` loop (especially when you are nesting loops). Finally, I would *default* to `NaN` that way you can handle `null` and empty arrays. Something like,

```
public static double displayLargest(double[][] arrayOfArray) {
    double maxValue = Double.NaN;
    if (arrayOfArray != null) {
        for (double[] array : arrayOfArray) { // <-- for each array in arrayOfArray
            for (double value : array) {      // <-- for each value in the array
                if (!Double.isNaN(maxValue)) {
                    maxValue = Double.max(maxValue, value);
                } else { // <-- the first value.
                    maxValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The largest value in the array is: " + maxValue);
    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat An array itself is an object. The array could be null, and in this case, an inner array could be null.