# Comparing 0 with Double min value

Tags: java

Why is the below returning false?

```
int i = 0;
if ((double) i > Double.MIN_VALUE)
    System.out.print("true");
else
    System.out.print("false");
```

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/why-is-double-min-value-in-not-negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's see what we get from Double.MIN_VALUE. When we say,

```
System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

It prints out that the minimum double value is 4.9E-324, which is **POSITIVE** and **NONZERO**.

In your code you compare it to 0. Even though how small 4.9E-324 is, it is still greater than 0.

If you are trying to find the smallest negative double that you can get, then you are looking for,

```
System.out.println(-Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

This will return `-4.9E-324`, which is the smallest and negative number that you can get with `Double`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Double.MIN_VALUE` is **positive** and **nonzero**. According to [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html):

> MIN_VALUE:
>   A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double,
>   2-1074. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal
>   0x0.0000000000001P-1022 and also equal to
>   Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).