# How to deal with zero division in the equation of chicken swarm optimization

Tags: java, matlab, stack-overflow, divide-by-zero, cloudsim

I am working on chicken swarm optimization using Java and I am a little bit recently learner of Java.

In the question below there are a small amount added to the equation of rooster position update to overcome the problem of division of zero.

In Matlab there is something called `realmin` which returns the smallest positive normalized floating-point number in IEEE® double precision.

Is there anything equivalent to this in java? I don't want to use exceptions.

```
tempSigma = Math.exp( (fitSortand_Index [anotherRooster ][1]  
        - fitSortand_Index [i][1]) / (Math.abs( fitSortand_Index[i][1]) + realmin ) );
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884879/2055998) helps.

Comment: Thank you it is much helpful

Comment: No need to replicate that truck. This is better:`if Math.abs(fitSortand_Index[i][1]) < 1e-6 then tempSigma = 0`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo please would you explain to me why ? I mean 1e-6 ..thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind. I think I misread the operation. [`realmin` is equal to `2^(-1022)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmin.html), which is about 2.225e-308. Just use that as a constant in your code. The exact value doesn't matter, I guess. But dividing any value by such a small quantity will yield a large number. `exp(.)` of a large number is likely to overflow, the result of the operation would likely be infinity, depending on the value of `fitSortand_Index [anotherRooster ][1]`, which could be 0 as well, I guess. I think this is a weird operation. What is the original MATLAB code?

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I am working on Java and I am new for JAVA but I know how to program in Matlab so it crosses my mind to use matlab instruction to make my self clear .. Thank you